# deleting object keys and reassign different keys is good approach on iteration of thousands of objects loop?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I was having array as example :-

for an example

```
 var a =[{name :"Adi", age:23},{name:"aman" ,age : 23},{name : rob,age:52}];
```

should i delete the keys name or should i assign it as undefined ,which approach is good ?
I means delete operator takes  much time or setting undefined should be good for so many iterations ?

Comment: This is a *primarily opinion-based* question because you're going to get a lot of **opinions** based of experiences, Etc.  Therefore, this question should be closed.

Comment: So will the new key names apply to all objects or will they change based on the object itself? Will every object in array go from name to naam and age to umra and subject to vishay?

Comment: Efficient how? Speed? Memory usage? I/O? Also, have you tried anything that you found to be not "efficient" enough?

Comment: 10000 is a tiny array, it starts to matter when there's millions :) So I'd just go with .map, though a simple mutating for loop would be more efficient in every way.

Comment: @Ryan yes all the object will contain the same keys as i mentioned ,it will apply to all objects , efficient enough in terms of  speed as well as memory so the page wont be  irresponsive.

Comment: @funkizer I just given you the starting figure it could go beyond the 50000 or more objects , do you have any idea how we can get the solution ,i mean javascript cant handle much data at client side right?

Comment: @Mike McCaughan Efficient enough in terms of speed as well as memory so the page wont be irresponsive

Comment: Why do you need to mutate the object?

Comment: Yeah i think the simplest possible for loop would do it. Beyond maybe 100-200k you can start to see a freeze of a second or few on lower end machines. Nothing except going webworkers or webasm can totally get rid of blocking.

Comment: Mutating instead of copying will save memory. Not sure about cpu but probably that too

Comment: @Hoyen I m passing an array to excell service which takes object keys as excell header names and i want different excell header names thats why .

Comment: I'm putting arrays of 50k+ things thourgh multiple .filter, .map and even rxjs/groupBy calls in one project actually when a user creates an xlsx, and the pause is barely noticable :)

Comment: @funkizer can you share code how i can achieve the same as you did?

Comment: @AdityaVashishtha are you able to update the excell service? If you can, you can probably create a Mapping table that maps the new key names with the original key names.

Comment: I'm doing nothing special, that's the point. Lots of piped rxjs operators and array.map etc :) It's not a concern unless you're targeting mobile users and got hundreds of thousands long arrays.

Comment: @Hoyen thing is that my api returning those array and for some reason api cant change object structure so we need to do this at client side,I am using angular 2 excell module  for same.

Comment: I'd suggest you write a working implementation, which _you think_ is optimal, and then send it to [CodeReview.se] (note that the way to ask there is different than hear, check their tour page - particularly, you want to include specific things you want to have reviewed, memory/time etc).

Answer (score 1):

The *fastest* way is to iterate them with raw `for` loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  const item = arr[i];
  if (item.hasOwnProperty('umra')) {
    item.age = item.umra;
    delete item.umra;
  }
  ...
}
```

If there is too much to process, the array can be processed in chunks, separated with zero timeouts. This allows to not block main thread with lengthy loop. Intermediate `setTimeout` or other async functions should run with `ngZone.runOutsideAngular` in Angular to not trigger change detection:

```
const CHUNK_LENGTH = 1000;

ngZone.runOutsideAngular(async () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (i > 0 && !(i % CHUNK_LENGTH)) {
      // new chunk
      await null;
    }

    const item = arr[i];

    if (item.hasOwnProperty('umra')) {
      item.age = item.umra;
      delete item.umra;
    }
    // ...
  }

  return arr;
})
.then(arr => {
  // .then triggers change detection after runOutsideAngular
})
```

Since promises have some overhead, it makes sense to switch to raw `for` and `setTimeout` for smaller chunks.

Compute-intensive tasks are supposed to be performed in web workers, but this is not the case, since there's not much computation, and same amount of loop cycles has to be performed after receiving results from web worker.

The *efficient* way is to not let this happen. If the object is received from API request and requires to be processed, API possibly should be changed.

Answer (score 1):

> Use **Web Workers** to prevent UI from Freezing

```js
var worker = run(function() {
  // Better than using if else for each key
  var keyMaps = {
    a: "x",
    b: "y",
    c: "z"
  };

  // Start when objects are available
  onmessage = function(e) {
    objs = e.data;

    // Loop through each object of objects list
    objs = objs.map(function(obj) {
      var o = {};

      // Loop through each key in each object
      for (k in obj) {
        o[keyMaps[k]] = obj[k]
      }

      return o;
    });

    // Let the main program know about the transformation
    postMessage(objs);
    self.close();
  };
});

// Just a wrapper to help create a Web Worker
function run(func) {
  return new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([`(${func})()`])));
}

// Response from API
var objs = [{
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
  },
  {
    a: 4,
    b: 5,
    c: 6
  }
];

// Pass in objs received from API
worker.postMessage(objs);

// Do whatever you want with the output
worker.onmessage = event => console.log(event.data);
```

> Explanation:

1. It doesn't matter if the objects are laid out flat, or nested within each other. The program will need to traverse each property `(p)` of each object `{o}`. There's no way to avoid `O(o * p)` time complexity.
2. Each object needs to be traversed, and within each object, each property needs to be traversed.
3. And only way to prevent UI from freezing is to write the logic within a Web Worker.
4. Use key map instead of if-else or switch statements, makes life easier!

Comment: Unfortunately, web worker won't help here, because property change isn't a costly operation, and performance impact comes from iteration itself. Same amount of resources (if not greater) will be spent on parsing serialized message from a worker.

Comment: @estus I beg to differ. The property key change can be a costly operation in case of converting a JSON that contains, name spaced, SOAP API era response. i.e. <ns3:name>, here a split or a regex needs to remove anything before a colon, (I was facing this problem in a project, with adamant back end programmers), which are fairly heavy operations and that too repeating for every key of every object.

Comment: I agree. But it won't in case of an object described in the OP. Any way, we'll never know what the case really was.